# Correct way to use bootstrap panel class?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have few question about bootstrap panel class:

1. can i use panel class in every rounded border box let's suppose i
   want to make rounded so can i use bootstrap panel class with panel
   body because don't padding?
2. can i use bootstrap panel class with sidebar class? Because my
   sidebar class style is look like as bootstrap default panel style so i
   don't want to make any specific class for it.

Here some screenshots where i want to know, can i use panel class with these div?

http://goo.gl/RlBO7A

Is this correct way to use panel class?

Comment: you want rounded border for the elements ?

Comment: yeah i just need rounded border

Comment: yeah i just need rounded border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `border-radius` for rounded borders

Just add this CSS to style section and use class `rounded-border` for the element to which you want rounded border.

```css
.rounded-border {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #345;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:6px;
}
```

```html
<div class='rounded-border'>I have border</div>
```